# What to do in this case of review?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This review looks like a something that should be a comment. But reading `this is the last try`, looks like the user who proposed the change is sure it is really better and should be updated. As I am not an expertise in these tags I don't know technically if it is correct. Should I just skip this revision, or reject as attempt to reply, or another thing?

[image]

Comment: Whether it's correct or not, it's an attempt to reply. The change itself, and the reason for the change, are invisible to most users this way; a (less raving, more-coherent) comment from the editor, explaining what needs to change and why, would be helpful.

Comment: The profile of the user who posted the original answer says active yesterday so the post isn't abandoned, and there's no comment at the bottom of the post asking for the fix so there's no permission. That the edit comment is abusive and was submitted anonymously certainly doesn't help.

Comment: If the edit is anonymous, its author probably has no an account. **How then he could left an comment?**

Comment: @Lol4t0 - If you're anonymous can you even see the results of the previous edit suggestions you've made? Possible they logged out because they wanted to be rude, and thought that it would make them harder to ban.

Comment: For some reason I remember there being a question very similar to this one posted not very long ago.

Comment: I'm confused. From what I can see of the edit history of that post, the original author made that change (along with several others) a week ago. When did this review appear?

Comment: @Dave: This question was posted around 22 minutes after the edit was suggested.

Comment: @gnat I'm not 100% sure if that dupe covers this story.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9968971) is the review which lead to the question.

Comment: Additional info: The user tried three times to edit the post, and was rejected every time: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9968170), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9968971), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9969841). The review above was from edit attempt #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what happened here is that the OP recently edited their answer, and inadvertently added a bug. Another user (or guest) has discovered this and wants to fix it. That's good! How they're going about it is not so good though...

Suggesting the edit was appropriate (whether they had an account or not), because this is, simply, a suggestion to edit the code. The OP will get a notification, and can choose whether the suggestion is acceptable.

Since the OP will see that notification, I would say the correct action for reviewers is to **Reject** (which they did), as it changes the meaning of the answer, which is something only the OP should do.

So far so good. The OP will eventually see their notification and might change the answer (if the suggestion is indeed a fix).

---

Moving on to the user's bad behaviour:

The user certainly should not have submitted multiple edits and left nasty comments, and if they have an account they should not have suggested an edit anonymously. Their comment should have explained why their edit is an improvement. The comments they left on this suggestion are totally unacceptable, and their later "Fixed errors" comment (found by rene) is still not as clear as it ought to be (though at least it's civil).

It's worth getting a moderator's attention for the offensive comments. I don't know what tools mods have for contacting anonymous users but they may be able to link the user to an account if they have one. Other than that, **Reject** the edit and leave it to the OP to decide.

Comment: _"Fixed errors" in the earlier edit rene found [...]:_ I think you refer to [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9969841). However, it seems that it was posted around 3 hours _after_ the edit with the unacceptable comment.

Comment: @honk that's a good point - I hadn't noticed. Makes the behaviour even stranger...

Comment: Maybe good cop, bad cop, good cop strategy...